# where is the firefox menu in ubuntu mate?

Tags: firefox, menu, mate

I recently installed ubuntu MATE 14.04.LTS as OS.
most programs bring a menu "below"/underneath the window-"bar" (I am sorry about the unspecific vocabulary, i'm noob) - you know, the place where you close,minimize or maximize windows and that also holds main infos about the prog (e.g. "Ask ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox").
firefox DOESNT. and keyboard shortcuts are @##*$.

any help?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by [edit]ing your question and clarifying exactly what you mean. Specifically, I for one don't understand what you mean by "keyboard shortcuts are @##*$.". Do you intend to say "not working"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. I understand that you are missing the menu-row with options such as "File", "Edit", "View", and so on, in Firefox.

This menu-bar is hidden by default in Firefox. To show it permanently, press <kbd>alt</kbd>. Click on "View", and then go down to "Toolbars". Make sure there is a tick (✔) next to "Menu Bar".

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Great idea (by developers), great solution (by Tom).